# The problem of support vector machine - How to minimize $||w||^{2}$ subject to constraints of the form $\alpha w_{1}+\beta w_{2}+b\geq\pm1$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, inner-products

I am studying the subject of support vector machines from an online
course.

I am given four points and their classification 
$$
x_{1}=((5,4),+),\, x_{2}=((8,3),+)
$$

$$
x_{3}=((3,3),-),\, x_{4}=((7,2),-)
$$

I was told to find take a pair of points with the same classification,
and find the best maximum-margin linear classifier that is parallel
to the line connecting those points.

In this case there are two classifiers to find, and I am trying to
find the one that correspond to the set of positive points.

The end goal is to minimize 
$$
||w||=w_{1}^{2}+w_{2}^{2}
$$

under the constraint that 
$$
\langle x_{i},w\rangle+b\geq1
$$

for $i=1,2$ and 
$$
\langle x_{i},w\rangle+b\leq-1
$$

for $i=3,4$.

**My progress:**

The line connecting the positive points have a slope of 
$$
\frac{3-4}{8-5}=-\frac{1}{3}
$$

so, from my understanding, $w$ have a slope of 
$$
-\frac{1}{-\frac{1}{3}}=3
$$

and so if $w\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is denoted by $w=(w_{1},w_{2})$ I
get $\frac{w_{2}}{w_{1}}=3$, hence $w=(w_{1},3w_{1})$ and I need
to minimize $||w_{1}||^{2}$ under the constraints that 
$$
5w_{1}+4w_{2}+b\geq1
$$
$$
8w_{1}+3w_{2}+b\geq1
$$

$$
3w_{1}+3w_{2}+b\leq-1
$$
$$
7w_{1}+2w_{2}+b\leq-1
$$

and substituting $w_{2}=3w_{1}$ the constraints are 
$$
17w_{1}+b\geq1
$$

$$
12w_{1}+b\leq-1
$$
$$
13w_{1}+b\leq-1
$$

(the first two inequalities translate after the substitution to the
same constraint)

How do I go at solving this optimization problem ?